# animate an FBX loaded object in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

using THREE.FBXLoader, how do I call the object to rotate in the animate function? (Uncaught ReferenceError: object is not defined) is the error, so how do I know how to reference it?

if I define object there is no error but still no animation:

```
var object = {
    rotation: {x: 0}
};


fbx_loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  fbx_loader.load(fbx[fbx_counter], function (object) {
  scene.add(object);
  object.name = 'new_fbx'
  object.getObjectById(12).rotation.x += 0.01
  console.log('id: ' + object.id);
  console.log('name: ' + object.name);
});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  // this is where the problem is:
  //object.rotation.x += 0.01
  //object.rotateX += 0.01
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating an `object` variable in the global scope but not assigning it to the model you are loading.

Try doing something like:

```js
var loadedModel;


fbx_loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  fbx_loader.load(fbx[fbx_counter], function (object) {
  loadedModel = object;
  loadedModel.name = 'new_fbx';
  loadedModel.getObjectById(12).rotation.x += 0.01
  scene.add(loadedModel);

  animate();
});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    loadedModel.rotation.x += 0.01
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: still not working... its odd is it some sort of js scope issue? (having the same problem in Babylon.js)

Comment: Try getting rid of this line


`loadedModel.getObjectById(12).rotation.x += 0.01`


Also sharing your code and error would be helpful

Comment: problem is I dont know how to reference the mesh outside of the .load function in 3js, in Babylon its just scene.getMeshByName("your_mesh_name")

Comment: loadedModel should become your mesh object. Again, sharing your code is essential to helping you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Since you can access your scene object in your animate function you could then get reference to the object and rotate it.

```
fbx_loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  fbx_loader.load(fbx[fbx_counter], function (object) {
  object.name = 'new_fbx'
  scene.add(object);

});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    // You have access to scene - Get 'new_fbx' object from it
    var fbxObject = scene.getObjectByName('new_fbx')
    // Make sure this object exists before accessing it
    if (fbxObject) {
       fbxObject .rotation.x += 0.01
       fbxObject .rotateX += 0.01
    }
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```